# Is it safe to add custom keys/strings pairs to root.plist file?

Tags: ios, settings, plist, bundle

I would like to generate my own settings views using this Rootplist, and add to it some properties would really be handy for that. 
Can one consider as safe to add custom Key/String pairs to Root.plist file from Settings.bundle?

For instance :

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>MyTitle</string>

    <key>_CustomKey</key>
    <string>FooBar</string>
    ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Take a look at this blog post [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/comment/reply/274).

Caveat: While I haven't tries this myself, what you describe seems to be the normal way of adding custom settings to a project.

So, my answer would be: Yes it's safe.

Comment: In the answer you've mentionned, they're talking about info.plist file, and according to the docs, it's effectively the place where you have to put your specific infos. My concern is slightly different ( and your answer may apply too ) as it's focused on the Root.plist file. In fact I wonder if the Settings Application will care about my custom keys and possibly cause problems.

Comment: good point.. I misread your question (completely). Just researching now